# Web Speech API - use own service

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

Reading [this](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/htmlspeech/XGR-htmlspeech-20111206/#introductory), and [this](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#introduction). It seems clear that we can use Web Speech API without google speech recognizer engine. But in all of this information I can't found anything that supports this. And allow me to do that. Is it really possible?

Comment: The specification allows for the *possibility* of browsers using more than one service for speech recognition. It does not *require* browsers to do so, nor to expose an API for JavaScript to pick the service. As things are, Chrome will interact with Google and Safari (for Speech Synthesis) with Mac OS X's / iOS's built-in speech engine. The services are not interoperable and it's going to be a while until there is some competition there, as good speech recognition currently requires a huge backend.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as per spec, sure its formally possible. Do you really want to use your own service? Check the [api description](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#api_description) . You should be able to set the 'serviceURI' property to your own speech recognition server for sure.

But as touffy mentioned, its really gonna be difficult to someone just create their own server very quickly as it requires a lot of machine learning/iterations and server resources to support this.